# How to record audio from device microphone and send it to server

Tags: android, ios, cordova, audio-recording, microphone

I want to record audio using the device microphone using Cordova.
I need to share the recorded input with other users - sending it to my API using HTTP requests.

Is there any plugin for that? I haven't found any.
What is RAW audio data? I have seen some plugins using this, but I don't actually understand - is it like image buffer and I can send this data using regular HTTP request and the users browser will translate it to sound in their end?
Is it possible to play the sound by the time the user speaks, without waiting him to finish the whole record, just like a call?

Please give me some info about this, or link to a working plugin because I found just none on this section.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Plugin `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture`

```
// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    for (var i = 0, i < mediaFiles.length; i++) {
        var filePath = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // Do somthing
        // Http Request
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
};

// start capture
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1});
```

Comment: But this one opens a brand new screen only for recording, instead of remain in the app. Isnt it?